# Django on .Net infrastructure?

Tags: .net, django, web-applications

I was reading [this](http://batsov.com/articles/2011/06/19/django-vs-rails/) post on Django vs Rails

And the author says

```
"The also the possibility to deploy Django apps on Java or .Net infrastructure using Jython or IronPython."
```

How does one deploy a Django app on .Net infrasture? I couldn't find any tutorials explaining such a thing. Or am I mis-understanding the author?

Also, when says he "app", does he mean like one "app" from a Django project or app as in full Django project (i.e. a web app).

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Jython is a Python interpreter implemented in Java and Ipython is a Python interpreter implemented in .Net. Consequently you can user either of those to run Python programs on the respective platform, utilizing all the benefits (and downsides) of that platform. Based on the article, I am pretty sure that the author meant Django projects when talking about apps.